# Spring REST Interceptor with dynamic values

Tags: java, spring, rest, interceptor

**Question in short:** How can I pass a dynamic value to Spring REST interceptor after the RestTemplate is Autowired?

**Now a detailed explanation:**

I have a Spring REST interceptor as below:

```
public class HeaderRequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor  {

  private final String headerName;

  private final String headerValue;

  public HeaderRequestInterceptor(final String headerName, final String headerValue) {
    this.headerName = headerName;
    this.headerValue = headerValue;
  }

  public ClientHttpResponse intercept(final HttpRequest request, final byte[] body, final ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
    HttpRequest wrapper = new HttpRequestWrapper(request);
    wrapper.getHeaders().set(headerName, headerValue);
    return execution.execute(wrapper, body);
  }
}
```

And then I configure my RestTemplate as below with the above interceptor:

```
@Bean
 public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
    interceptors.add(new HeaderRequestInterceptor(<<MY-CUSTOM-HEADER>>, <<MY-DYNAMIC-VALUE>>));

    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory());
    restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
    return restTemplate;
}
```

Please look at the way I am creating the interceptor. MY-CUSTOM-HEADER is a constant, but MY-DYNAMIC-VALUE can change for every request. How can I make the interceptor take dynamic value?

PS: This is a standalone spring application (not web). It's a kind of client library that will be used to make REST calls.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the usage of interceptor if your headers are dynamic per request. 
Request based scope bean on RestTemplate can solve the issue but it creates RestTemplate object per request.

Simply adding a static utility class called HttpRequestHeaderUtils.java with addHeader() method and call it before calling RestTemplate methods or wrap it on your own CustomRestTemplate to delegate all calls of RestTemplate to have single implementation.

```
CustomRestTemplate extends RestTemplate{


}
HttpRequestHeaderUtils.java 
public static void addHeader(final HttpRequest request, final String headerName, final String headerValue)
  HttpRequest wrapper = new HttpRequestWrapper(request);
  wrapper.getHeaders().set(headerName, headerValue);
}
```

If you still want to use interceptor, you can hijack your intercept method 
by storing the dynamic value as a request attribute (which is not clean, its same as setting header directly instead )

```
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(final HttpRequest request, final byte[] body, final ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
    HttpRequest wrapper = new HttpRequestWrapper(request);
    final String dynamicHeaderValue = request.getAttribute("myDynamicHeaderValue");
    wrapper.getHeaders().set(headerName, dynamicHeaderValue!=null? dynamicHeaderValue : headerValue );
    return execution.execute(wrapper, body);
  }
```

Comment: Using a wrapper or util class is too primitive in my opinion. I know that can be done, but I am looking for something that is easier/smarter to implement. Also, please consider that the headers are dynamic, but not per request though.

Comment: How do you get/set the dynamic headers if not per request ?

Comment: It's completely random. Think of it as a short-living oauth tokens.

Answer (score 0):

If the header value can change in every request, the `RestTemplate` bean should have the `request` scope

```
@Bean(scope = DefaultScopes.REQUEST)
@ScopedProxy
public RestTemplate getRestTemplate(HttpRequest request) {
  // ...
  interceptors.add(new HeaderRequestInterceptor(
              "custom-header"
            , myDynamicVal));
  //
}
```

I used a scoped proxy because I assumed the enclosing class is injected in the default (singleton) scope. Also note that I added the HttpRequest as a dependency in the `getRestTemplate()` method assuming that you need request data to fill the header - if you don't simply remove it and add whatever you like.

Comment: You can use `@Scope("request")` then

Comment: Are you sure that request scope can be used in a non-web spring application too?

Comment: What is the default scope if you don't specify it?

Comment: Default scope is singleton